# Import native android source code to android studio and build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I synced the entire project and tried to import the native app source (Contacts, People) to Android Studio. How can I achieve this? ( I tried to link the sdk folder in the source project and the studio doesn't recognize the sdk folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compile android source applications such as Contacts,People without the whole android source code. At least not as-is without doing some porting work.

There are many dependencies which go all the way to the framework.